# How to set multiple cookies in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

What's the easiest way to set 3 cookies in a controller action using Zend Framework 2?

I tried using php's setcookie function to set multiple cookies..

```
$domainName = '.something.com';
$expirationTime = 2592000 + time();
setcookie("cookie1", "abc", $expirationTime, '/', $domainName);
setcookie("cookie2", "def", $expirationTime, '/', $domainName);
setcookie("cookie3", "ghi", $expirationTime, '/', $domainName);
```

However, it seems to set only the last cookie, which is cookie3. So, I am wondering if Zend framework 2 has a way to set multiple cookies like the above?

Thanks,

Comment: As a ~3K user, you should know we expect more detail and effort in a question here. What have you tried?

Comment: Griping like this with no answer to a simple question, doesn't look good on a ~7k User like you. So, if we are done measuring meaningless reputations, try reading the question before commenting.. Ever wondered the question doesn't need me to write any code?

Comment: Ha ha, good one! However, you may know [we're making an enhanced effort to downvote/close no-effort questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow). That's not to say you didn't _put_ effort into your question, but you didn't demonstrate any. My point was that a user of your rep would know this (from personal experience, or seeing other people try it). So, no offence intended - just bear in mind the PHP tag (hopefully) will demand more prior research in the future. (Close vote withdrawn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [zend framework 2 manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.http.cookie.handling.html)

```
$domainName = '.something.com';
$expirationTime = 2592000 + time();    
$cookie1 = new Zend\Http\Cookie('cookie1',
                               'abc',
                               '$domainName',
                               $expirationTime,
                               '/path');
$cookie2 = new Zend\Http\Cookie('cookie1',
                               'def',
                               '$domainName',
                               $expirationTime,
                               '/path');
$cookie3 = new Zend\Http\Cookie('cookie1',
                               'ghi',
                               '$domainName',
                               $expirationTime,
                               '/path');
```

Something like this.